# Proof regarding the function $\cos(1/x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, proof-writing

> Prove that for every number $a>0$ there exists 2 numbers $x,y$ with $0<x,y<a$ for which $f(x)>0$ and $f(y)<0$ with $f = \cos(\dfrac{1}{x})$.

How do I go about proving this?

Comment: I think you are asking for 2 numbers $0<x,y<a$ for which $f(x)>0$ and $f(y)<0$ since $f(x)$ can't be positive and negative.

Comment: The period as $x$ goes to $0$ becomes $0$, that's obviously the reason, but how to incorporate it.

Comment: @Pedro yeah that's what I meant.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, since we cannot have $f(x) > 0$ and $f(x) < 0$ for a single $x$.  Perhaps you are referring to two different values of $x$?

Comment: Just express $x$ in the form $\frac{1}{n\pi\alpha+b}$, with well chosen $\alpha$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $a>0$ there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{2\pi n}<a$.

Then take $x=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$ and $y=\frac{1}{\pi(2n+1)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a^{-1} > 0$.  Choose a positive integer $n$ such that $x^{-1} = 2\pi n > a^{-1}$,  Then $x = (2\pi n)^{-1} < a$, and $f(x) = \cos(2\pi n) = 1$.  We also have $y^{-1} = (2n + 1) \pi > a^{-1}$, so that $y < a$, with $f(y) = \cos (2n + 1)\pi = \cos \pi = -1$.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***